# Running a Python Script using Pyzo from the Editor

Tags: python, editor, pyzo

This is my first time to use python. I am using IDE Pyzo and trying to run the following script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from numpy.random import normal,rand
x = normal(size=200)
plt.hist(x, bins=30)
plt.show()
```

When I run it line by line from the shell it is working. But when I try to run it from the editor "Run the file as script" it gives the following error:

```
>>> %cd "c:\program files (x86)\pyzo"
  File "<console>", line 1
    %cd "c:\program files (x86)\pyzo"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> %run -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\pyzo\Test.py"
  File "<console>", line 1
    %run -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\pyzo\Test.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how to run the script without error?

Comment: Put from numpy.random import .... in a new line, not after plt

Comment: I did this but still got the same error: >>> %cd "c:\program files (x86)\pyzo"
  File "<console>", line 1
    %cd "c:\program files (x86)\pyzo"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> %run -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\pyzo\Test.py"
  File "<console>", line 1
    %run -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\pyzo\Test.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>>

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the two imports on different lines

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from numpy.random import normal,rand
```